# Using blas/Lapack in Fortran file for R

Tags: r, cmd, fortran

I have the following problem. I have a file say file.f90 in which I have implemented some Fortran subroutines, say called foo. Then I compile these functions using "R CMD SHLIB file.f90". To use the function foo in a seperate R file I then use dyn.load("foo.dll") and to call it .Fortran("foo", ...).

So far so good. But now I need to use some functions implemented in Lapack.

I have no idea how to do this or where to have a look. I have only tried calling "R CMD SHLIB file.f90 -llapack" but already there I get an error that llapack has not been found. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:
I have finally found an answer to my question with the help of everyone here and with looking up much on the internet. I have to say the solution is quite easy but as I am quite a noob when it comes to these things it still took some time. So here s my solution for Windows 11 and R studio 4.1

Assume that our R session/project has the path PATH_PROJ, e.g "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\MyProject". Then I created a new folder named "f90files" in which I intended to save all Fortran functions, so PATH_PROJ\f90files.
Next, I needed the path of my R's Lapack PATH_LAPACK, e.g "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2\bin\x64\Rlapack.dll".

In PATH_PROJ\f90files I then implemented the Fortran subroutine as suggested by Jean-Claude Arbaut:

```
subroutine eigvals(n, a, vre, vim, info)
    implicit none
    integer :: n, info
    integer, parameter :: lwork = 65536
    double precision :: a(n, n), vre(n), vim(n)
    double precision, save :: work(lwork)

    call dgeev("n", "n", n, a, n, vre, vim, 0d0, 1, 0d0, 1, work, lwork, info)
end subroutine
```

Following this, I started up Windows command prompt and typed

```
gfortran -shared PATH_LAPACK PATH_PROJ\f90files\eigvals.f90 -o PATH_PROJ\f90files\eigvals.so -o PATH_PROJ\f90files\eigvals.dll
```

and further

```
gfortran -shared PATH_LAPACK PATH_PROJ\f90files\eigvals.f90 -o PATH_PROJ\f90files\eigvals.so
```

(maybe this can be done in one go?)

With this all was nicely compiled. In R I then loaded the function using

```
dyn.load("PATH_PROJ\f90files\eigvals.dll")
```

Finally, using the implementation given below, I ran

```
eigvals <- function(a) {
  if (is.matrix(a) && is.double(a) && nrow(a) == ncol(a)) {
    n <- nrow(a)
    s <- .Fortran("eigvals", n = as.integer(n), a = a, vre = double(n), vim = double(n), info = 0L)
    structure(complex(real = s$vre, imaginary = s$vim), info = s$info)
  } else stop("Invalid input")
}


eigvals(a)
```

and voilà we are done! Thanks again to everyone!

Comment: Have you told R/the linker where to find the lapack library?

Comment: As I m a bit of a noob I m not sure what you mean. How would one do that? or look for an answer?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Is the LAPACK library containing directory  in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `ld.so.conf` or equivalent? What operating system dou you even use?

Comment: Please don't use lazy/non robust code, use the full path and extension. e.g. ```"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\R.exe" CMD ...```

Comment: @Compo When did hardcoding paths become the robust way of doing things? I work on several machines, with different OS, different R version, and different install directory for R (and never in Program Files). Yet I use the same scripts. Never hardcode paths. Ever.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is *generally* a bad idea, and wouldn't help here anyway since it is used by the (Linux!) *runtime linker*, not the compile-time linker.

Comment: @Compo No, that's nonsense. Configure your PATH properly, then you can use short binary names. This isn't lazy, it's widespread best practice because it's the *only* way of having portable code.

Comment: You should never need to configure or rely upon the end user having configured the PATH variable. Not only are their too many examples to count throughout these pages of it being misconfigured or just plain deleted, it isn't the only thing that is being relied upon here, the variable named PATHEXT is too. When you are scripting, you are writing the commands only once, and as such there is no huge time saving by omitting paths. If there's multiple instances, you can create a variable yoursrlf, i.e. ```Set "_r=%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.2.2\bin\R.exe”```, then use ```"%_r%" CMD ...```.

Comment: Typing just `r` first of all tries to locate a file named `r` in the current directory, if found it then parses the `PATHEXT` values, in order first to last until a match is found, suffixing that extension to the `r` basename. If a match is not found in the current directory, the process starts again, this time replacing the current directory with the first location listed within the `PATH` variable values, it will continue through that list one by one, in order, each time suffixing the cycled list from `PATHEXT`, until it locates its first match. It will run that file whether correct or not.

Comment: So I ran the following on the windows command prompt as suggest by the answer:  "cd PATH_WHERE_PROJECTFILES_ARE" to change into the appropriate directory and then I ran  "gfortran -shared C:\Programme\R\R-4.1.2\bin\x64  eigvals.f90 -Rlapack  -o eigvals.dll" ... Then I m getting a an error  "cannot find C:\Programme\R\R-4.1.2\bin\x64: Permission denied" ... Although Rlapack is in that path for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libraries you are looking for are Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll in the R-4.2.2\bin\x64 directory (replace 4.2.2 with your version).

Here is an example. Let's compute eigenvalues using LAPACK's `dgeev`.

Fortran file `eigvals.f90`. Here to simplify `lwork` is a constant, but in "real" code you would have to do this more carefully.

```
subroutine eigvals(n, a, vre, vim, info)
    implicit none
    integer :: n, info
    integer, parameter :: lwork = 65536
    double precision :: a(n, n), vre(n), vim(n)
    double precision, save :: work(lwork)

    call dgeev("n", "n", n, a, n, vre, vim, 0d0, 1, 0d0, 1, work, lwork, info)
end subroutine
```

Compile with either one of the following commands (change the path as necessary). If you are on Windows, do this from the Rtools bash window. On Linux the extension is .so and not .dll.

```
gfortran -shared -L/c/App/R/R-4.2.2/bin/x64 eigvals.f90 -lRlapack -o eigvals.dll
R CMD SHLIB eigvals.f90 -lRlapack
```

In R, you can now do, assuming you have `setwd()` to the directory containing the DLL:

```
a <- matrix(c(2, 9, 4, 7, 5, 3, 6, 1, 8), 3, 3, byrow = T)

dyn.load("eigvals.dll")
is.loaded("eigvals")

eigvals <- function(a) {
  if (is.matrix(a) && is.double(a) && nrow(a) == ncol(a)) {
    n <- nrow(a)
    s <- .Fortran("eigvals", n = as.integer(n), a = a, vre = double(n), vim = double(n), info = 0L)
    structure(complex(real = s$vre, imaginary = s$vim), info = s$info)
  } else stop("Invalid input")
}

eigvals(a)
```

Pay attention to the number and type of subroutine arguments in `.Fortran`, otherwise you may crash R. Note also that you must call Fortran subroutines, not functions.

I you are on Windows and using R-4.2 with Rtools 4.2, there is an extra trick: the compiler is no longer in the default directories. See [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/howto-R-4.2.html). You have first to do, in the Rtools bash window:

```
export PATH=/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin:$PATH
```

If you are using the compiler from the Windows command prompt, you will have to modify the PATH environment variable accordingly.

Comment: Thanks already for the great answer!! You are my hero already. I have however still a problem. I have adapted everything to the specific paths. But when I type the above it tells me that the gfortran is not found. Does that mean that the gfortran compiler is not accessible to R 4.1.2? I am on Windows 11 and using R 4.1.2.

Comment: I decided to try it from the windows command prompt which for me looks like "gfortran -shared C:\Programme\R\R-4.1.2\bin\x64 -lRlapack -o eigvals.dll" ... It throws a permission denied error.. sorry for all these noob questions :P

Comment: @Warlock1 You have to install Rtools for your version of R. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/). For you it's Rtools 4.0. It's basically a custom install of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), designed to work well with R packages. You may use another compiler, but I suggest you stick with this one, to avoid more problems (typically with the version of DLLs used by gfortran).

Comment: @Warlock1 When Rtools is installed, you are not done yet: either you run gfortran from the usual Windows command line, or from the MSYS2 shell (the one labelled "MinGW64"). In both cases you have to make sure gfortran is in the PATH. In Rtools it should be in `C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin`. You may also need `C:\rtools40\usr\bin` for some commands. You may start with Windows command line if you are not familiar with MSYS2. Then just do `PATH C:\rtools40\mingw64\bin;C:\rtools40\usr\bin;%PATH%` and you should be able to compile. Try first with a simple "hello world" to check everything is in place.

Comment: If you use the MSYS2 shell, note that paths are not written the same way: `C:\MyFiles\hello.f90` becomes `/c/MyFiles/hello.f90`. You have also a bash shell, with some usual Linux commands, and the GCC toolchain.